# libsvm classifying - at bad stage so far

Tags: java, libsvm

Problem: I have certain set of data to be classified - Useful(1)/Useless(0). I will provide full set of data as input for training purpose of the classifier. and test with different data set.

For this, I am trying to convert my data to LIBSVM format. before doing anything, I thought of providing numeric input of one vector and check the result.

Input:

Training: 1 1 2 (the first 1 indicates useful Class in this vector followed by numeric input)
Testing: 1 1 2(I am not sure of input data format)

Output:

(0:0.9982708183417436)(1:0.0017291816582564153)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)

I dont have class 0 in training set, but it has probEstimated for class 0.

I am not really sure of how to convert my data to numeric vector input and fetch the data from the numeric test data set to equivalent Data as supplied. ANY HELP IN THIS REGARD IS HIGHLY APPRECIATED.

Planned tasks:
1. Load all the data to Hash tables and get the keys to be saved in data sets with respective classifier - USEFUL(1).
2. Supply the data set to the svmTrain and get the model.
3. Prepare test data set(Convert each word/phrase to respective numeric value saved training set, if found. Else, assign a new value).
4. Supply the test set and model to the SVM's EVALUATE method. 
5. Get the resultant vectors from the USEFUL class and re-map to the data.

Code: used from different sources.

public class Datatosvmformat {

```
static double[][] train = new double[1000][3];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashMap<String, Integer> dataSet = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    double[][] test = new double[10][3];

    train[1][0] = 1;
    train[1][1] = 1;
    train[1][2] = 2;

    svm_model model =  svmTrain();
            //Test Data Set  
    double[] test1 = new double[3];
    test1[0] = 1;
    test1[1] = 1;
    test1[2] = 2;
    evaluate(test1,model);

    }

    private static svm_model svmTrain() {
        svm_problem prob = new svm_problem();
        int dataCount = train.length;
        prob.y = new double[dataCount];
        prob.l = dataCount;
        prob.x = new svm_node[dataCount][];     

        for (int i = 0; i <dataCount; i++){             
            double[] features = train[i];
            //ystem.out.println("Features "+features[i]);
            prob.x[i] = new svm_node[features.length-1];
            for (int j = 1; j < features.length; j++){
                svm_node node = new svm_node();
                node.index = j;
                node.value = features[j];
                prob.x[i][j-1] = node;
            }           
            prob.y[i] = features[0];

        }               

        svm_parameter param = new svm_parameter();
        param.probability = 1;
        param.gamma = 0.5;
        param.nu = 0.5;
        param.C = 1;
        param.svm_type = svm_parameter.C_SVC;
        param.kernel_type = svm_parameter.LINEAR;       
        param.cache_size = 20000;
        param.eps = 0.001;      

        svm_model model = svm.svm_train(prob, param);

        return model;
    }

    public static double evaluate(double[] features, svm_model model) 
    {
        svm_node[] nodes = new svm_node[features.length-1];
        for (int i = 1; i < features.length; i++)
        {
            svm_node node = new svm_node();
            node.index = i;
            node.value = features[i];

            nodes[i-1] = node;
        }

        int totalClasses = 2;       
        int[] labels = new int[totalClasses];
        svm.svm_get_labels(model,labels);

        double[] prob_estimates = new double[totalClasses];
        double v = svm.svm_predict_probability(model, nodes, prob_estimates);

        for (int i = 0; i < totalClasses; i++){
            System.out.print("(" + labels[i] + ":" + prob_estimates[i] + ")");
        }
        System.out.println("(Actual:" + features[0] + " Prediction:" + v + ")");
        return v;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but the problem could be due to the fact that you need to mark positive examples with `+1` and negative examples with `-1`.

Otherwise, the libsvm software could asssign an arbitraty class (e.g. `0`) to the training vector `1 1 2`, since it iterprets the first elem of the feature vector as a feature value (and not the label class).

So try to change the class label 1 in +1 for positive examples (and -1 for negative examples).

Usually, for data format for libsvm is the following:

```
<label> <index1>:<value1> <index2>:<value2>
```

where:

- label is the class label (e.g. +1/-1)
- indexN is the feature Id (i.e. the number that identified a certain feature)
- valueN is the feature value (i.e. the value assigned to the specified feature: 0/1 for binary features or 0,1,2,... for categorical features)

An example of the data format accepted by the libsvm tool can be found at this page:
[LIBSVM Data: Classification (Binary Class)](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/binary.html)

There are many datasets that you can explore in order to understand the data format accepted by the libsvm tool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, got some clarity. Thanku.